# ModelForm's cleaned_data returns None for FileField with empty string input

Tags: django, django-forms

Consider a model with the nullable filefield.
I'm encountering a puzzling behavior with Django's ModelForm when it comes to handling a FileField. I have noticed that when the FileField receives an empty string ('') as the file data, the cleaned_data dictionary of the ModelForm returns None for that field instead of ''.

Additionally, I observed another related behavior:
If i have 2 entries
`Model.objects.create()` and `Model.objects.create(file='')`

`Model.objects.filter(file__isnull=True)` will return empty queryset and `Model.objects.filter(file='')` will return both the entries

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, this is the expected behaviour. If you pass an empty value to a `FileField`, it'll return None. [The code for `FileField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fce90950bef348803fa7cc3e6bc65f4bce429b82/django/forms/fields.py#L641) has the following:

```py
    def to_python(self, data):
        if data in self.empty_values:
            return None
```

You should probably be passing a file object to a `FileField`!